# Program ends, but console still hanging

Tags: java, console-application

This program is to generate perfect numbers. My code seems to be fine, but for some reason **it stops working after the 7th perfect number**. After taking a closer look at the console, I realize that my program doesn't terminate.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static int amount = 509;

    public static long m;
    public static long n;
    public static double o;
    public static double p;
    public static int q = 1;
    public static boolean prime = true;
    public static boolean mersennePrime = true;

    public static void prime() {
        if (m % 2 == 0) prime = false;
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= m; i += 2) {
            if (m % i == 0) prime = false;
        }

        if (m == 1) prime = false;
        if (m == 2) prime = true;
    }

    public static void mersennePrime() {
        if (prime) {
            o = Math.pow(2, m) - 1;
            for (int i = 3; i * i <= o; i += 2) {
                if (o % i == 0) {
                    mersennePrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else mersennePrime = false;
    }

    public static void perfectNumber() {
        if (mersennePrime) {
            p = (o * (o + 1)) / 2;
            System.out.println(q + ". " + m + ": mersenne prime = " + o + ", perfect number = " + p);
            q++;
        }
    }

    public static void reset() {
        prime = true;
        mersennePrime = true;
        n = 0;
        o = 0;
        p = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= amount; i++) {
            m = i;
            prime();
            mersennePrime();
            perfectNumber();
            reset();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my output:

1. 2: mersenne prime = 3.0, perfect number = 6.0
2. 3: mersenne prime = 7.0, perfect number = 28.0
3. 5: mersenne prime = 31.0, perfect number = 496.0
4. 7: mersenne prime = 127.0, perfect number = 8128.0
5. 13: mersenne prime = 8191.0, perfect number = 3.3550336E7
6. 17: mersenne prime = 131071.0, perfect number = 8.589869056E9
7. 19: mersenne prime = 524287.0, perfect number = 1.37438691328E11

Comment: Can you provide any output you are getting?

Comment: First thing: get rid of all those global variables. Learning to code like that will just bite you later. You should pass the numbers into the function directly.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is `if (o % i == 0)` in `mersennePrime` method.** `o` is double type variable. `double` is not accurate to perform modulo operation (%) on it. In this program, value of `o` is increasing for each prime number. For example: for number 61, value of o is `2.305843009213694E18`. And doing modulo operation on it, I don't think it will have much accuracy.

Actually your program keeps running (I have gone upto 131th number which took about 10 minutes). But prints nothing after 7th perfect number because `if (o % i == 0)` is not performing accurately and letting everything to come in it's block. For this reason, even the number for which `mersennePrime` should be true, are becoming false. As no `mersennePrime` is true, no perfect number is found later after 7th perfect number.

Using [**`BigDecimal`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of `double` will solve your problem I think.

Also, be careful about `for (int i = 3; i * i <= o; i += 2)` because `i * i` itself an integer. As `o` can be much bigger, an integer number won't be able to keep up with it.

Comment: When I change o from double to BigDecimal, it gives me many errors, such as "the operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) int, BigDecimal." Do you know how I would resolve this?

Comment: @DR there's no operator overloading in Java (unlike in C++), BigDecimal is a class, therefore should be used as one. Refer to [this tutorial](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial) for more insight.